# Ansible: Filter one IP belong to which net ipaddr

Tags: list, filter, ansible

At first I wrote a simple filter to decide in which environment an ip belongs to:

```
vars:
  testip0: 10.160.30.20
  testip1: 10.190.2.25
  ip_range_live: 10.160.0.0/22
  ip_range_qa: 10.170.0/22
  ip_range_devel: 10.180.0.0/22

filter:

datacenter: 
"{% if ansible_default_ipv4.address | ipaddr(ip_range_live) %}live
 {% elif ansible_default_ipv4.address | ipaddr(ip_range_qa) %}qa
 {% elif ansible_default_ipv4.address | ipaddr(ip_range_devel) %}devel
 {% else %}INVALID{% endif %}"
```

(formatted for better readability)

This works fine!
But now the problemis comming ...
Now we got a new ip-range for live

```
ip_range_live: [ 10.160.0.0/22, 10.190.0.0/22 ]
```

But the ansible ipaddr filter can't work with a list (on the right side)

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

For example,

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "ip: {{ item }} ranges: {{ list_of_ranges }}"
      loop:
        - 10.160.30.20
        - 10.190.2.25
      vars:
        ranges:
          live: [10.160.0.0/22, 10.190.0.0/22]
          qa: [10.170.0/22]
          devel: [10.180.0.0/22]
        list_of_ranges_str: |-
          {% for k,v in ranges.items() %}
          {% for i in v %}
          {% if item|ansible.utils.ipaddr(i) %}{{ k }}{% endif %}
          {% endfor %}
          {% endfor %}
        list_of_ranges: "{{ (list_of_ranges_str|length > 0)|
                            ternary(list_of_ranges_str.split('\n')|unique,
                                    'INVALID') }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  msg: 'ip: 10.160.30.20 ranges: INVALID'
  msg: 'ip: 10.190.2.25 ranges: [''live'']'
```